# Providing similar login experience while logging in with a button and with enter

Tags: forms, login, submit

It regards standard login forms - I mean those which include login/email field and password field **and** "remember my login" checkbox, which is often forgotten to click although user would be actually interested in selecting this option.

Of course user can navigate between form fields with a tab, so s/he can tab-navigate to checkbox field and press space to check it. But I doubt many users will do it, so I'm just wondering if there are any better ways to achieve it.

Are there any best practices? Or maybe it is not statistically important at all (I have no stats regarding how many users click "Sign in" button vs. submitting login form with enter).

Comment: With jQuery? $(function() {
    $('form').each(function() {
        $(this).find('input').keypress(function(e) {
            // Enter pressed?
            if(e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
                this.form.submit();
            }
        });

        $(this).find('input[type=submit]').hide();
    });
});
</script>

Comment: That would only hide submit button for anyone who has javascript enabled and send the form on enter keypress. It does not deal with the checkbox at all, and it's jQuery code rather than UX pattern. Besides, I don't think having submit button hidden would be a good idea at all. It would just limit users options to log in only to pressing enter (while some of them could be unaware of such possibility) and deteriorate the affordance of the whole form.

Comment: If you have reason to believe that most users would prefer to have their login credentials remembered, maybe that should be the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are many ways to approach this problem, each with certain benefits and drawbacks, but there is no ideal catch-all.

One case is to leave it by default enabled (eg, [Gmail](https://www.gmail.com)). While there are drawbacks, like what if people don't want to stay logged in, don't notice it, etc. However, this is the most convenient - as stated on the Gmail site, quote below.

> For your convenience, keep this checked. On shared devices,
>   additional precautions are recommended. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2917834?p=securesignin&rd=1).

Depending on the security level of your site, you can change what the checkbox does, like make it only remember the username, which is what all banking sites do.

Alternatively, your idea of having the tabbed users go from username > password > remember checkbox also works (eg. [Facebook](http://facebook.com))